# Node.js Spawning multiple threads within a class method

Tags: node.js, multithreading

How can I run a single method multiple times multi-threaded when called as a method of a class?

At first I tried to use the `cluster` module, but I realize it just re-runs the *whole* process from the start, rightfully so.

How can I achieve something like what's outlined below?

I want a class's method to spawn *n* processes, and when the parallel tasks are completed, I can resolve a promise which the method returns.

The problem with the code below is that calling `cluster.fork()` will fork `index.js` process.

**index.js**

```
const Person = require('./Person.js');
var Mary = new Person('Mary');
Mary.run(5).then(() => {...});
console.log('I should only run once, but I am called 5 times too many');
```

**Person.js**

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
class Person{
    run(distance){
        var completed = 0;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            for(var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                 // run a separate process for each 
                 cluster.fork().send(i).on('message', message => {
                     if (message === 'completed') { ++completed; }
                     if (completed === distance) { resolve(); }
                 });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem again? also fork (which cluster module uses internally) won't start the process from the beginning, but right from where it is called. If you could reword your question so that it depicts exactly what you want, maybe I could try something.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I think you're wrong about that. Common examples of fork show a check for `isWorker` in an if/else statement before the fork.

Comment: It seems like it's a default behaviour of cluster.fork(). Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626750/why-is-node-cluster-fork-forking-the-parent-scope-when-implemented-as-a-module

Comment: @kabanus yeah I was talking in context of fork syscall which does show this behavior, however, I might be wrong about cluster module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is impossible. It's even worse - this has nothing to do with `js`. To multi (process or thread) in your particular problem you will essentially need a copy of the object in every thread, since it needs (maybe) access to fields - in this case you would need to either initialize it in every thread or share memory. That last one I don't think is provided in `cluster`, and not trivial in other languages in every use case.

If the calculation is independent of the Person I suggest you extract it, and use the usual (in `index.js`):

```
if(cluster.isWorker) {
    //Use the i for calculation
} else {
    //Create Person, then fork children in for loop
}
```

You then collect the results and change the Person as needed. You will be copying `index.js`, but this is standard and you only run what you need.

The problem is if results are dependent on Person. If these are constant for all `i` you can still send them to your forks independently. Otherwise what you have is the only way to fork. In general forking in `cluster` is not meant for methods, but for the app itself, which is the standard forking behavior.

**Another solution**

Following your comment, I suggest you checkout [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) or `child_process.exec` on same file.

This way you can spawn a totally independent process on the fly. Now instead of calling `cluster.fork` you call `execFile`. You can use either the exit code or stdout as return values (stderr etc.). Promise is now replaced with:

```
       var results = []
       for(var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
             // run a separate process for each 
             results.push(child_process.execFile().child.execFile('node', 'mymethod.js`,i]));
        }

        //... catch the exit event from all results or return a callback using results.
```

Inside `mymethod.js` Have your code that takes `i` and returns what you want either in the exit code or through stdout, both properties of the returned `child_process`. This is a bit un-`node.js`-y since you're waiting on asynchronous calls, but you're requirements are non standard. Since I'm not sure how you use this perhaps returning a callback with the array is a better idea.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to figure this out to be within a class method so someone could easily require the module without modification to their script

Comment: @d-_-b If I understand what you're getting at, then I think you're out of luck. An option would be for the method to call an external app, and that could be forked. Would that would be OK?

Comment: Yes! I think that could be a viable option. Is that just spawning a child process and abstracting the class out of that other process call?

Comment: @d-_-b Then `child_process` maybe for you. Check my answer.

Comment: @d-_-b Can you award me the bounty? Otherwise the points go to waste.

Comment: will do, but pretty sure the highest voted answer gets it automatically

Comment: Read about it now - half in general, but if bounty is made by OP who accepts then the accepted answer is awarded everything. Thanks anyway!